# Keyboard navigation in WPF Grids

Tags: wpf, keyboard, navigation, grid, itemscontrol

Suppose you have a StackPanel, which contains a ScrollViewer which contains another StackPanel with an ItemsControl with a bound ItemsSource. This ItemsSource is bound to a collection of Grids created at runtime. Each Grid contains a label and a textbox/combobox/a few checkboxes that all have a unique TabIndex value within the StackPanel. 
Here is the xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" MinWidth="500" Width="Auto">
    <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl"                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow, Path=GridsCollection,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to simply tab from one control to the next, but only within the controls in the grids in the grids collection. So far I've tried different KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation settings but without any luck. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please could you post some XAML / code to illustrate the scenario and precisely what it is you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `TabNavigation` to [`KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode.aspx) for each container you want to behave like that, so the focus won't escape it as long as you use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(grid1, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
```

If you want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour, use [`KeyboardNavigation.SetControlTabNavigation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.setcontroltabnavigation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This though, causes the focus to be placed in the different controls within one (given) grid. I actually have a collection of grids so the focus needs to shift from one grid to the next or from one control inside a grid to the next control inside the same grid. I have tried to set KeyboardNavigation to the StackPanel and the StackPanel's ItemControl, but without any luck.

Comment: As stated in the reaction to another answer in this post, the problem lies in the Visibility of the controls in the dynamically created grids. I will get back to this later. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply an implicit style that disables tabbing for every Control, then you re-enable it for just what you want to be tab-able:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ScrollViewer.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Control">
          <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      </Style>
  </ScrollViewer.Resources>
  <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" MinWidth="500" Width="Auto">
    <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl"                          
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SomeWindow, Path=GridsCollection,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Don't forget to set IsTabStop on your dynamically generated Grids to True

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.Grid does not seem to have an IsTabStop property in .Net 4.0, but apart from that, thank you for your answer. I've tried it and found out why both answers don't work: the controls in the dynamically created grids have IsVisible set to false at runtime, though I can still see them and explicitly set the visibility in code. Another challenge... :)